# hamiltonian cycle python wrong answer

Tags: python, algorithm, hamiltonian-cycle

given n as number of nodes and edges as a list of edges

can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code. It works on some instances but doesnt work for all of them

```
for edgeindex in range(len(edges)):
    alltrue = [True]*(n)
    visited = [False]*(n)
    S = []
    start = edges[edgeindex][1]
    visited[start] = True
     S.append(start)
     nex = start
     for edgeindex2 in edges[edgeindex:]:
         if edgeindex2[0] != nex:
             continue
         if visited[edgeindex2[1]] == False:
             visited[edgeindex2[1]] = True
             S.append(edgeindex2[1])
             nex = edgeindex2[1]
         if visited == alltrue:
             return 'yes'
return 'no'
```

Comment: You code is not indented properly please fix it.

Comment: instead of `visited == alltrue` you can do `all(visited)`. Also, as Kobi K said, please fix the indent. It would help if you could provide examples.

Comment: sorry, there its indented

Comment: `if visited == alltrue:` should not be used, you should use: `if all(visited):`

Comment: @thefourtheye CodeReview.SE is intended for working code that you want reviewed, not for wrong piece of code.

Comment: @thefourtheye Please read the [faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of a site before suggesting migration. You couldn't be more wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a greedy approach, and add the next edge it can travel to - to your path. However, this greedy approach does not work for the Hamiltonian Path Problem (which is NP-Complete, so there is no known 'efficient' solution to it...)

**Failing example:**

```
G = (V,E), V = {1,2,3}, E = {(1,3),(1,2),(2,3)}
```

Now, assume you are starting from 1, and travel first through (1,3). At this point you are done, and you cannot find a Hamiltonian Path. However, the path 1->2->3 exists and you won't find it.

**Solution:**

The simplest way to solve Hamiltonian Path is to generate all possible [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), and check if any of them forms a Hamiltonian Path. There are more efficient (and complicated) solutions - but they too require exponential running time.